# $f:R\to S$ is finite injective and $S$ is of dim $1$

Tags: ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

Let $R$ be a local noetherian domain of dim $3$. I'm asked to construct examples $f:R\to S$ with the following properties:
1- $f$ is onto and $S$ is of dim $1$.
2- $f$ is injective and $S$ is of dim $1$.
3- $f$ is finite (as R-algebra) injective,  and $S$ is of dim $1$.

- For the 1st, I take $f:R\to S=R/p$ , where $p$ is of codim one.
- For the 2nd, I take $f:R\to S=k[x]$ , where $k$ is quotient field of $R$.
- For the 3rd, I dont know if it is possible or not? can you give a hint please?

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you want $R\subset S$ where $S$ is a finitely generated $R$-algebra of dimension 1?

Comment: your examples for 1 and 2 look good! for question 3, this is indeed not possible. since $f$ is finite, it is in particular [integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_element#Integral_extensions), and integral extensions of a subring [always](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2558457/show-that-dima-leq-dimb) have the same dimension.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: if u pose the comment as answer the question would excluded from unanswered ones.

Comment: @1400 done! happy it helped :)

Comment: I find 3 not so trivial if one assumes what I've asked in my previous comment.

Comment: @John yes, I'm not sure either if one just wants $S$ to be _finitely generated_ rather than finite. maybe we should be able to localize a subset of a minimal generating set of the maximal ideal of $R$ to get a solution? but I'm not sure how to make it work without additional hypothesis on $R$. maybe worth asking as a separate question!

Comment: If this is what you meant then why accepted an answer which supposes that $S$ is a finitely generated $R$-module? Are you confused by the two definitions?

Comment: oh dear; 1400, if you meant _finitely generated_, as @John proposed, then you should unaccept my answer!! my answer assumes you meant _finite_ in the sense that $S$ is finitely generated as an $R$-module

Comment: the homomorphism $f$ makes $S$ an $R$-module; as noted in page 27 of Atyiah-Macdonald. - I mean $S$ is finite ring extension of $R$. i.e. $S$ is finitely generated R-module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your examples for 1 and 2 look good! For question 3, this is indeed not possible. Since $f$ is finite, it is in particular [integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_element#Integral_extensions), and integral extensions of a subring [always](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2558457/show-that-dima-leq-dimb) have the same dimension.